# add more than one templateUrl in One component in angular2

Tags: angular

angular2 allows to write muliple-line html code using back-ticks(`).
 but when using templateUrl, i dont know how adding more than one html file.

when i try this..

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
           <h1>view1</h1>
           <h1>view2</h2>
            `
})

class Appcomponent{

}
```

like that.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './HTML1.html','./HTML2.html'


})

class Appcomponent{

}
```

together with HTML1.html and HTML2.html

HTML1.html

```
<h1>view1</h1>
```

HTML2.html

```
<h1>view2</h1>
```

can i using multiple templateUrl in angular2?
thanks for your time to read this :)

Comment: Which is the objective?  Why do you need 2 html files?

Comment: i'm trying to dividing long html files for edit source code conveniently.. but realized that it is useless.. thx :)

Comment: you may want to consider whether the need of dividing long html is just a sign of the need of refactoring the code and create smaller components

Comment: Thank you for reply my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add more than one HTML file. I also don't see what purpose this would fulfill.

You can use `*ngIf` or `*ngSwitchCase` to show only parts of the template if that is your intention

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
           <h1 *ngIf="view == 'view1'>view1</h1>
           <h1 *ngIf="view == 'view2'>view2</h2>
           <button (click)="view = view == 'view1' ? 'view2' : 'view1'">toggle</button>
            `
})

class Appcomponent{
  view = 'view2';
}
```

Comment: Actually I think this would be a nice feature to enable HTML template reuse in other pages.

Comment: @jfajunior you can use inheritance. I don't see a use for multiple templateUrls.

Comment: @Gunter What is, in your opinion, the most elegant way to have, for example, a modal window with data and OK/Cancel buttons where you can reuse in several pages? I didn't find yet a simple and clean solution yet. I saw this good example: https://gist.github.com/jnizet/15c7a0ab4188c9ce6c79ca9840c71c4e , and I might be wrong, but it seems like reusing HTML templates would be easier. Is there an easier way?