# Is there a way to include stand-alone html files into your x.component.html?

Tags: angular

Say this is your app.component.html file

```
<div id='blah'>
..  100 lines here...
</div>

<div id='blahblah'>
.. another 500 here
</div>

<div id='blahblahblah'>
.. another 400 and so on... 
</div>
```

I know this is ridiculous but I just want to set up the ground for the question.

Obviously, this is a long .html that is difficult to navigate. It would be nice to break things into more manageable chunks and let Angular  bring the related piece at run time ( or even at transpile time ), even that would be totally welcome!

Here is the question:
Is there a way in Angular that you take these 3 divs and put them in their own standalone html files (such as blah.html blahblah.html & blahblahblah.html) and then somehow tell angular to include them so they are as good being embedded in the app.component.html?

From the php world, you'd be doing something like include ('blah.html'). I know in HTML, we do not have such a thing, but not sure about Angular? Seeing what Angular does, I thought, this might have been taken care of too.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40882858/1009922), it is not possible.

Comment: You could make each div its own custom component

Comment: But then those components won't be able to have access to all the vars and methods compared to their original place. Right?